# Detect direction of drag when trying to scroll beyond the limits of scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In my vertical `scrollView` (having 2 `containerView`s of the size of device screen) I want to hide a `View` (added to my window) when user scrolls down, but don't want to hide it when the user scrolls up, i.e., when `scrollView`'s `contentOffset.y` is currently 0 and on again trying to scroll it remains to be 0 only.

```
if self.scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0
{
    myView.isHidden = true
} 
else if self.scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
    myView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: How do you handle this operation? Using `UIScrollViewDelegate`?

Comment: yes, I have put this in scrollViewWillBeginDragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set scrollViewDelegate to VC, then:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    myView.isHidden = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y < 0
}
```

Comment: scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y >= 0 doesn't this mean dragging down?
for dragging down I want to I don't want to hide.
BTW, I got the approach. Thanks buddy :)